# using javascript setTimeout causes a loss of data within an object?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

**Background:**
I've written a javascript object called `Step` to implement a step-type event for any operation I might need to use for my website, e.g. smooth-motion functions. I can register functions in it to run each step by using the Step object's method, `registerFunction(func)`.

To handle running the functions every step, the Step object has another method called `run()`.
In this method I run through the list of registered functions, run them, and *then* call the `setTimeout(...)` function, passing the reference to the run function to recall it for the next step.

**Problem:**
The first 'step' is run by the onload event (attribute) in the <body> tag of my html page (indirectly, though: `Step.run` is called by a function `initiateJS()` which is called by  `onload`). Nothing goes wrong in the first step. However, by the second step, the variables within the Step object seem to have been disposed; they all become undefined.

**Questions:**
I was thinking it might be due to the garbage collector? Maybe it somehow loses its reference?
Also, is using `setTimeout(...)` even the best method of making a step-type event implementation?

**Details:**
The Step object is declared in the js document somewhat as:

```
    var Step = {
            myVars: "somevalues",
            anArray: [],
            run: function() {
                //run the registered functions
                setTimeout(this.run,this.interval);
        };
```

ALSO, in the next step, the `Step` object is still existent.

Some other minor details:

I'm using Chrome

I'm making my website with XAMPP full

I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use setInterval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` runs code in the global context. `this` is no longer defined the next time `run()` executes. You'll need to refactor your code to either declare variables on some kind of global object, or to pass references into the run function itself.

edit: since you said `Step` is global, this should work:

```
run: function() {
    //run the registered functions
    setTimeout(Step.run, Step.interval);
}
```

Comment: How would I declare a global object that would preserve its variables?

Answer (score 1):

Change your run function to this:

```
run: function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(that.run, that.interval);
}
```

The setTimeout function [redefines the `this` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_%27this%27_problem) and this is the simplest way I can think of to work around this issue.

Comment: Won't this still break, because `this` is still undefined the next run is executed? And so `that` will be set to undefined?

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. And I don't see how this answers the problem at all.

Comment: Rather, `this` is the `window` object next time it's run. Putting `var that = this` in the function accomplishes nothing, since you're effectively doing `var that = window`, and `window.run` is still undefined.